# Spring batch dynamic file writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, batch-processing

Does spring batch provide any dynamic/generic file writers? For example, if i have multiple requirements of generating a file and i have one view created for each purpose, all i want to do is specify the view name and i want spring-batch to extract the data from the view to a flat file with column headings. This is as simple as if you have used dbviz or sql developer, just export the result of a query to a file.

Recently i had 4 different requirements of extracting data to file, and i have repeated the config file and created a record bean and record mapper to map the bean to the columns of view for each file. Rather than repeating this entire process every time, i am looking to see if Spring batch or any other java frameworks provides a generic approach to extracting a file based on the table and its columns without writing result set mappers or dealing with field extractors.

I can build a generic spring batch file extractor but wanted to check if spring-batch already does that, which seems like a basic thing?

Also if i create a generic extractor then the attributes of the bean will be kinda dynamic based on the columns names of the view. So in that scenario, if i have about 50 columns i dont want to specify each attribute in fieldExtractor, i want all the attributes to be extracted. Currently i am specifying attributes in spring config as given below, but i don't want to spefiy the attribute names. I just want to say extract all attributes. Is that possible?

```
<bean id="CsvItemWriter" class="some.class.FileWriter" scope="step">
  <property name="resource" value="file://#{jobParameters['file.name']}"/>        

  <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
  <property name="lineAggregator">
     <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
        <property name="delimiter">
              <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB" />
        </property>

        <property name="fieldExtractor"> <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
              <property name="names" value="name.last, name.first, name.middle, birthDate, gender,  homePhone, cellPhone"/>
           </bean>
        </property>
     </bean>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some one needs it, i found a similar question in SO that was difficult to find. I am using columnMapRowMapper as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931623/spring-batch-and-spring-integration)

Comment: Thanks..Do you know the oppositie implementation of this..The reader will read from a flat file and the writer will write to a DB table.Is there anything similar to ColumnRowMapper for Flat file writer?

Comment: Also could you specify how you solved the issue of defining the header with the column names. Thanks in advance :)