# Spring Batch ItemWriter with Dynamic Header

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Have to create a Spring Batch Job with **dynamic data** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931623/spring-batch-and-spring-integration) . However while writing unable to add the Headers to the FlatFile(CSV) generated. I tried passing in Execution Context but that doesn't seem to work. Could somebody guide how the column names can be dynamically added in this case.

The writer I am using for this dynamic data is as follows:

```
public FlatFileItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> getWriter() throws Exception {
        String reportName = getReportName();
        saveToContext(reportName, reportPath);

        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(String.join(File.separator, reportPath, getReportName()));

        FlatFileItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> flatFileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        flatFileItemWriter.setResource(resource);
//NEED HELP HERE..HOW TO SET THE HEADER TO BE THE KEYS OF THE MAP
//flatFileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback();
        flatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Map<String, Object>>() {

            {
                setDelimiter(delimiter);
                setFieldExtractor(
                        new PassThroughFieldExtractor<>()
                );
            }
        });
        flatFileItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return flatFileItemWriter;
    }
```

Comment: Where do the column names come from? ie what is dynamic here? This is very important to correctly design a solution to your problem. Please provide an example of what you are trying to achieve with the input/output of your job.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud. Have edited the post to add the necessary details/code. please do let me know if any other details are needed from my end. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, you still did not mention where this map is coming from? How is it filled in? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve *without* referring to Spring Batch and give an example of input/output data?

Comment: Hi Mahmoud. so the idea is that the data itself will be dynamic. That means the column names and the data are all flexible and have to be handled in as generic a manner as possible. To do so, I am using  ColumnMapRowMapper which maps the data into Map<String, Object> where String is the columnName and Object are the values in that column for the data.

Comment: I now want to Write a custom HeaderCallback which would be able to dynamically put the keys of the Map as the header of the file(the rest pf the writer code is mentioned in the Question) . Let me know if I am missing any further details.